# ifstream will not open

Tags: c++, file

The file exists in the directory, and I've tried running Visual Studios in Administrator Mode. However, `ifstream` can not find the file I give to it.
Here is the code I am using:

```
std::ifstream instream;
instream.open("appdata.txt");

if (!instream)
{
    std::cout << "Could not find appdata.txt!";
}
```

But I am always greeted with `Could not find appdata.txt!` when I run the program. [image: My Directory]

Here is a picture of my directory, for proof that I have it spelled correctly and it exists.

So, my question is, am I missing something so glaringly obvious that I am glazing over it each time I look? I can not figure out for the life of me why instream can not open `appdata.txt`.

Comment: Are you sure that the program is run from the directory the file is in and has permission to read the file?

Comment: You could use something like [ProcMon](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/processmonitor.aspx) to inspect which paths are being tried for the file

Comment: Are you sure the file isn't called `appdata.txt.txt`? Turn on file extension display in Windows Explorer  - your `BallBuster.exe` is being displayed as `BallBuster` so perhaps the same is happening to the other files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a problem with current directory being set to something else than a dir where your file is (usually your home folder if executing from explorer).
Try executing the program from command line from directory where your file is.

EDIT
If you want to set the working directory to some specific location, check this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363806.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Add the file by right clicking on project name on visual studio interface. 
This will keep your file in the right directory.

If you want to add in the directory by yourself, first add a file using the method I said above and the find which is the folder you should keep so that you can use that file by mentioning just the file-name. And then you can add your files in that folder.